# how to cut columns of csv

Tags: shell, ubuntu, csv

I have a set of csv files (around 250), each having 300 to 500 records. I need to cut 2 or 3 columns from each file and store it to another one. I'm using **ubuntu OS**. Is there any way to do it in command or utility?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you know that the column delimiter does not occur inside the fields, you can use cut.

```
$ cat in.csv
foo,bar,baz
qux,quux,quuux
$ cut -d, -f2,3 < in.csv 
bar,baz
quux,quuux
```

You can use the shell buildin 'for' to loop over all input files.

Comment: You can scalably process all files with something like:

find "*.csv" | xargs cut -d, -f2,3 > out.csv

Comment: You can use the `--output-delimiter=STRING` option of `cut` if you want to get rid of the comma or change it to something else.

Comment: The main problem with this answer is that `cut` doesn't handle quoted fields that include the delimiter. If your CSV file has data that does this, you'll need to use something else.

Answer (score 12):

If the fields might contain the delimiter, you ought to find a library that can parse CSV files. Typically, general purpose scripting languages will include a CSV module in their standard library.

```
Ruby:   require 'csv'
Python: import csv
Perl:   use Text::ParseWords;
```

Comment: While the answer really shows us the way,  it would benefit if it contains a complete solution.

Answer (score 11):

If your fields contain commas or newlines, you can use a helper program I wrote to allow cut (and other UNIX text processing tools) to properly work with the data.

https://github.com/dbro/csvquote

This program finds special characters inside quoted fields, and temporarily replaces them with nonprinting characters which won't confuse the cut program. Then they get restored after cut is done.

lutz' solution would become:

```
csvquote in.csv | cut -d, -f2,3 | csvquote -u
```

Comment: Yes it worked very good for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199311/how-to-delete-a-column-columns-of-a-csv-file-which-has-cell-values-with-a-string/29134579#29134579

Answer (score 0):

If you used `ssconvert` to get the CSV you might try:

```
ssconvert -O 'separator="|"' "file.xls" "file.txt"
```

Notice the **TXT** extension instead **CSV**, this way will use *Gnumeric_stf:stf_assistant* exporter instead of *Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv*, which let you use options (`-O` parameter). Otherwise you'll get a *The file saver does not take options* error. Pipe character is much more unlikely, but you might want to check before.

Then you can rename it and do things like:

```
cat file.csv | cut -d "|" -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

- Other options example: `-O 'eol=unix separator=; format=preserve charset=UTF-8 locale=en_US transliterate-mode=transliterate quoting-mode=never'`.
- [A solution with AWK v4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199311/how-to-delete-a-column-columns-of-a-csv-file-which-has-cell-values-with-a-string/29134579).
- [`ssconvert` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ssconvert.1.html).