# How to delete a column/columns of a CSV file which has cell values with a string enclosed in double quotes

Tags: unix, csv, cut

How can I delete a column from a CSV file which has comma separated value with a string enclosed in double quotes and a comma in between? I have a file 44.csv with 4 lines including the header like the below format:

```
column1, column2, column3, column 4, column5, column6
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between",4432,6787,890,88
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between",890,88,12,455
11,22,"simple string",77,777,333,22
```

I need to cut the 1,2,3 columns from the file, so I used the cut command as below

```
cut -d"," -f1,2,3 44.csv > 444.csv
```

I am getting the output as

```
column1, column2, column3
12,455,"string with quotes
4432,6787,"another string with quotes
11,22,"simple string"
```

But I need the output to be

```
column1, column2, column3
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between"
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between"
11,22,"simple string"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dhruuv.

Comment: `Cut` won't help you here. I'd consider using a programming language with real csv support, e.g. Python.

Comment: Does your file 44.csv always have 4 lines? If so, 4 lines isn't much at all. I would just clean it manually.

Comment: No, it has more than 400-500 lines in each file and I have to do this in each file. Above was just a sample to understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU awk` version 4 or later, you can use `FPAT` to define the patterns.

```
gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" OFS="," 44.csv
```

#### Test:

```
$ gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" OFS="," mycsv.csv
column1, column2, column3
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between"
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between"
11,22,"simple string"
```

Comment: Mine is GNU Awk 3.1.5. How can I achieve this. Coz with your code i am getting the output as column1, column2, column3,

12,455,"string with quotes,

4432,6787,"another, string with

11,22,"simple string",77,777,333,22

Comment: It won't work on `GNU awk 3.1.5`. `FPAT` was introduced in version 4.

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Comment: I am not sure of that as I am new to Linux and do not know if this is installed... I am trying to check.

Comment: I did this at the command line: perl -v
Output: This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi...........

This means I have perl installed... Any alternative solution to the above question?

Comment: This did the trick for me. However in my case the fields may also be empty, so I had to do: `gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")" OFS="," 44.csv`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you Dhruuv, the solution proposed by jaypal singh is correct but wasn't  working for all my cases.
I recommend you to use : https://github.com/dbro/csvquote (Enables common unix utlities like cut, head, tail to work correctly with csv data containing delimiters and newlines) this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with cut in this special case, by using `"` as your delimiter, but I'd strongly advise against it -- even if you could make it work in this case, you might later get a string with an escaped double quote in it, e.g. `\"` which would fool that too. Or, more of your columns might be quoted (which is a perfectly valid CSV-ism).

A smarter tool is required! The simplest to obtain might well be Perl and the Text::CSV module -- you've almost certainly got Perl installed, and depending on your environment installing Text::CSV as a package, with CPAN.pm, or with cpanminus ought to be straightforward.