# Deleting colums of large csv files

Tags: linux, csv

I have a large CSV file of around 2 GB, containing 7 columns. I want to delete its 4th column which is a text (snippet). I used "cut" command like:

> cut -d, f 4 -- complement file

But it is not removing the column because it is making columns whenever a comma is encountered in a row and deleting the 4th column from that row. Following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392990/how-to-cut-columns-of-csv),  i used [csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote) like:

> csvquote file | cut -d ","  -f 4 --complement | uniq -c | csvquote -u

it worked for a small file, but throwing an error for large files:

> errno: Value too large for defined data type

I want to know some solutions for deleting columns of the large data file. Thanks.

Edit: Head file output:

> funny,user_id,review_id,text,business_id,stars,date,useful,type,cool
>   0,WV5XKbgVHJXEgw7f-b6PVA,hhmpSM4LcHQv6noXlYYCgw,"Went out of our way to find this place because I read they had amazing poutine. Worth the traveling. It really was spot on amazing. Served out of a storage container this place is hip. $10 for two huge portions of poutine. The fries were crisp and held up to the creamy gravy well. Topped with a huge portion of squeaky white cheese curds this was a fantastic meal.

Comment: it's good to show the fragment of the input file

Comment: just copy the output of `head file` command and paste here

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Done. thanks for the clarity. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried telling cut to use the other fields instead?

Like this:

```
trucks | cut -f 1,3- -d , | uniq -c | csvquote/csvquote -u
```

I tested it on my machine and it seems to work.  But I didn't see a sample of your data, also you didn't note which program is throwing the

> errno: Value too large for defined data type

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the same command for other fields, not working. I guess the problem is with the size of the file. csvquote is throwing that error.